# Check correct columns in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a lot of files and I would like to test, if file is valid, then keep it else delete it.

Valid file may looks like:

cat in.tsv

```
LRG_293 het rs144848 c.1114A>C 1
LRG_293 het rs1799943 c.-26G>A 1
LRG_293 hom rs1799955 c.7242A>G 6
LRG_293 hom  c.7242A>G 6
LRG_293 hom rs1799955  6
LRG_293 hom rs1799955 c.7242A>G
```

Also some of the columns (3,4,5) can be empty, so I would like to print all rows, if any of the row passed this condition.

File is tab separated. Always contain 5 columns and:

```
1.column: Need to start LRG*
2.column: Could be only het or hom
3.column: start rs*
4.column: start c.*
5.column is integer 1-6 numbers.
```

Invalid files may look:

cat invalid1.tsv

```
LRG_292 het 0/1_of_1  
LRG_292 het 0/1_of_1  
LRG_292 het 0/1_of_1
```

or

```
LRG_292 het   1
LRG_292 het   1
LRG_292 het   1
```

or

```
LRG_292 het rs1060915 c.4308T>C 0/1_of_1
LRG_292 het rs16940 c.2311T>C 0/1_of_1
LRG_292 het rs16941 c.3113A>G 0/1_of_1
LRG_292 het rs16942 c.3548A>G 0/1_of_1
```

I prefer any bash or awk solution.

My try was something like (for check last column is numeric and all number of columns is 5):

```
#!/bin/bash

re='^[0-9]+$' # integer
mkdir wrong_format
mkdir good_format

for i in *tsv;

do 

col=$(awk '{print NF}' $i | sort -nu | tail -n 1) # number of columns
fifth=$(awk -F "\t" 'NR==1{print $5}') # print first character from last column

if ! [[ $fifth =~ $re ]] && ! [[ $col == 5 ]] ; then

mv $i wrong_format

else

mv $i good_format

fi

done;
```

OUTPUT should look like:

cat in.tsv

```
LRG_293 het rs144848 c.1114A>C 1
LRG_293 het rs1799943 c.-26G>A 1
LRG_293 hom rs1799955 c.7242A>G 6
LRG_293 hom  c.7242A>G 6
LRG_293 hom rs1799955  6
LRG_293 hom rs1799955 c.7242A>G
```

So basically script should check the all files in directory - if at least on row is under the condition above - save all file (keep all rows) to new file, Otherwise remove file.

I am not sure how to add another conditions mentioned above. Also I would like to create code more consistent.

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: there are several things that `Also some of the columns (3,4,5) can be empty, so I would like to print all rows, if any of the row passed this condition.` might mean. Print all rows in the file or print the rows that have all those fields empty or print when at least one is empty? Print to a new file or stdout or stderr? Should files with those criteria be considered to have passed or failed the tests on those fields? [edit] your question to clarify your requirements and **show the expected output** when those conditions occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This awk should work for you:

```
awk -F '\t' '$1 ~ /^LRG/ && $2 ~ /^h(et|om)$/ && $3 ~ /^rs/ && $4 ~ /^c/ && $5 >= 1 && $5 <= 6' file
```

This will print all valid records to output.

---

**EDIT:**

To solve this issue:

> Would you be able to add condition - if at least one row passed condition, then print all. Because some of rows can be empty I noticed. See edit

You can use:

```
awk -F '\t' 'NR==FNR{
   if (NF==5 && $1 ~ /^LRG/ && $2 ~ /^h(et|om)$/ && $3 ~ /^rs/ &&
       $4 ~ /^c/ && $5 >= 1 && $5 <= 6) {
      a=1
      nextfile
   }
} a' file file
```

Comment: Nice awk solution thank you. When I try to test in valid file in prints nothing. Any idea?

Comment: I tested it on your input and it prints all the records. Try: `awk '$1 ~ /^LRG/ && $2 ~ /^h(et|om)$/ && $3 ~ /^rs/ && $4 ~ /^c/ && $5 >= 1 && $5 <= 6' file`

Comment: Thank you - second seems work. Would you be able to add condition - if at least one row passed condition, then print all. Because some of rows can be empty I noticed. See edit.

Comment: ok then try this awk command: `awk 'NR==FNR{if (NF==5 && $1 ~ /^LRG/ && $2 ~ /^h(et|om)$/ && $3 ~ /^rs/ && $4 ~ /^c/ && $5 >= 1 && $5 <= 6) {a=1; nextfile}} a' file file`

Comment: thats works perfectly fine. Only when last column contain for example 0/1_of_1 - you script process file like valid. Maybe the last number (*_1) script takes as integer? Valid column is only integer 1 to 6. Thank you so much!

Comment: In my testing `0/1_of_1` in last column is not being printed as valid. You can also test as: `awk '$1 ~ /^LRG/ && $2 ~ /^h(et|om)$/ && $3 ~ /^rs/ && $4 ~ /^c/ && $5 >= 1 && $5 <= 6' <<< 'LRG_293 hom rs1799955 c.7242A>G 0/1_of_1'`

Comment: Yeah true - thank you for good response. It is works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Bash / grep / regex solution:

```
 grep -v -P '^LRG[^\t]*\t(het|hom)\trs[^\t]*\tc\.[^\t]*\t[1-6]$' filename
```

This prints bad lines within given `filename`.

To extract only good lines from a file to another:

```
 grep -P '^LRG[^\t]*\t(het|hom)\trs[^\t]*\tc\.[^\t]*\t[1-6]$' badfile > goodfile
```

Comment: This won't ensure there are exactly 6 fields though, if there are more then the `.*`s will cause it to break.

Comment: @123 yep, fixed :)

Comment: @EdMorton `-P, --perl-regexp: Interpret PATTERN as a Perl regular expression (PCRE, see below).  This is highly experimental and grep -P may warn of unimplemented features.` ? Neither `-E` or `-G` can handle this

Comment: Huh. I stand corrected. Apparently unlike sed and awk, GNU grep at least doesnt recognize `\t` as representing a tab character unless you use `-P` (or use  the `$'\t'` bashism). How bizarre. I wonder if other greps have the same issue.

Comment: @EdMorton Not that surprising as `\t` isn't specified by POSIX for either ERE or BRE.

Comment: @123 still, I do find it surprising given that the tools we most commonly think of as also providing grep-like functionality (sed, awk, perl, etc.) all do interpret `\t` as a literal tab character. Oh well, learned something new.

Comment: @EdMorton Lol, 2 hours I struggle to make it works with BRE ! haha, well, ok we both learned something today, ty ^^

Answer (score 2):

If you are using GNU awk, you can just pass all the files in and have it determine validity with something like this:

*parse.awk*

```awk
BEGINFILE { v = 1 }     # assume valid 
!(                      \
     $1 ~ /^LRG/        \
  && $2 ~ /^h(et|om)$/  \
  && $3 ~ /^rs/         \
  && $4 ~ /^c/          \
  && $5 >= 1 && $5 <= 6 \
) {                     # If one condition fails, run this block
  v = 0                 # Flag file as invalid
  nextfile              # Move on to next file
}

ENDFILE { 
  printf FILENAME " is%s valid\n", v?"":" not"
  system("mv \"" FILENAME "\" " (v?"good_format/":"wrong_format/"))
}
```

Run it like this:

```
gawk -f parse.awk files...
```

Answer (score 2):

You're going to want:

```
mkdir -p good_format
mkdir -p wrong_format
for i in *.tsv; do
    awk -F'\t' '
        NF == 5           &&
        $1 ~ /^LRG/       &&
        $2 ~ /^h(et|om)$/ &&
        $3 ~ /^rs/        &&
        $4 ~ /^c\./       &&
        $5 ~ /^[1-6]$/    { next }
        { exit 1 }
    ' "$i"
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        mv "$i" good_format
    else
        mv "$i" wrong_format
    fi
done
```

Note that in the above awk is doing what it's designed to do (parsing/manipulating text within files) while the shell is doing what it's designed to do (creating/destroying files/processes).

Comment: Hi Ed, thank you. I have in my good_format all files empty. Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: Either a) your input files were empty, or b) you added `-i inplace` to the command line and are using gawk which then zapped your input files since the script doesn't produce any output, or c) you added `> "$i"` to the end of the awk command line and that allowed the shell to zap your input files. Otherwise nothing I can think of could cause that.

Comment: I just noticed, that some of my column (only columns 3,4,5) can be empty (this value missing). Would be possible, if only one row passed condition, print all in that file?

Comment: Are you asking if the script does that or if it can do that? If you're asking if it does that - No, the awk script doesn't produce any output, just an exit status. If you're asking if it can be modified to do that - sure, it's software so anythings possible.

Comment: Yes, I am asked for modify the script :-)

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking to do (write something to the input file? write to unique output files per input file? write to stderr? something else? print an error message or one failing line or all failing lines or something else?) so edit your question to include whatever it is you need to handle in your example and include the updated expected output given that more comprehensive input.